# How to remove Spring Data CustomConversions warnings from application startup?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have an application with the following Spring dependencies:

```
starterBase    : 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:2.2.1.RELEASE',
starterActuator: 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:2.2.1.RELEASE',
starterJpa     : 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:2.2.1.RELEASE',
starterTest    : 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:2.2.1.RELEASE',
starterWeb     : 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.2.1.RELEASE',
elasticsearch  : 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch:2.2.1.RELEASE'
```

In the moment that I added the elasticsearch dependency, the following Warnings appeared when I start the application:

```
WARN  [main] o.s.data.convert.CustomConversions.register - Registering converter from class org.springframework.data.geo.Point to interface java.util.Map as writing converter although it doesn't convert to a store-supported type! You might wanna check you annotation setup at the converter implementation.
WARN  [main] o.s.data.convert.CustomConversions.register - Registering converter from interface java.util.Map to class org.springframework.data.geo.Point as reading converter although it doesn't convert from a store-supported type! You might wanna check you annotation setup at the converter implementation.
WARN  [main] o.s.data.convert.CustomConversions.register - Registering converter from class org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.geo.GeoPoint to interface java.util.Map as writing converter although it doesn't convert to a store-supported type! You might wanna check you annotation setup at the converter implementation.
WARN  [main] o.s.data.convert.CustomConversions.register - Registering converter from interface java.util.Map to class org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.geo.GeoPoint as reading converter although it doesn't convert from a store-supported type! You might wanna check you annotation setup at the converter implementation.
```

I debugged the code, and in spring-data-commons:2.2.1-RELEASE in CustomConversions.java, there is a private method with name 'register' in line 196, and its javadoc mentions the Mongo types, and it is strange, because we are not using Mongo. Is this Mongo reference correct?

But the main question is, is there any way to avoid/remove these warnings?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This code was refactored into spring data commons in April 2017, and the comment was copied from the original place and not adapted. So this is no mongo specific stuff here.

As for the warnings, all you can do at the moment is ignore them, we'll check if we need these at all.

**Addition:**

there is [an issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACMNS-1615) for that, the [corrsponding PR](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/pull/421) is in the pipeline of being processed. So hopefully these warnings will be dealed with soon.

Comment: Update: mentioned issue and PR are closed, problem still present. [Created a new issue ticket](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/issues/2287)

Answer (score 7):

I fixed it with adding to my `application.yml`:

```yaml
logging.level.org.springframework.data.convert.CustomConversions: ERROR
```

Comment: You could remove 'pattern.dateformat' to reduce possible confusion.

Answer (score 1):

If you use log4j2, you may ignore this error by adding a specific log level for this package, something like the following.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="info">
            <!-- <AppenderRef ref="........"/> -->
        </Root>

        <Logger name="org.springframework.data.convert.CustomConversions" level="ERROR"></Logger>
    </Loggers>

</Configuration>
```