# How to avoid CustomConversions warning in spring framework

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

How to avoid CustomConversions warning related to org.springframework.data.geo.Point in spring boot startup

```
2020-11-17 13:04:32.850  WARN 42991 --- [           main] o.s.data.convert.CustomConversions       : Registering converter from interface java.util.Map to class org.springframework.data.geo.Point as reading converter although it doesn't convert from a store-supported type! You might want to check your annotation setup at the converter implementation.
```

Comment: Please check the url https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60001034/how-to-remove-spring-data-customconversions-warnings-from-application-startup

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove Spring Data CustomConversions warnings from application startup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60001034/how-to-remove-spring-data-customconversions-warnings-from-application-startup)

Answer (score 0):

With [Dmitry Kaltovich](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9834603/dmitry-kaltovich) 's answer, I solved my problem with these codes like below: I added application.yml file. You can write that below codes in file.

```
logging:
pattern.dateformat: yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS,Europe/Minsk
level:
root: INFO
org.springframework.data.convert.CustomConversions: ERROR
```