# How to configure spring.data.convert.CustomConversion for MSSQL date

Tags: sql-server, datetime, spring-data, datetime2

Recently I noticed that our spring-boot services are logging a warning from `org.springframework.data.convert.CustomConversions`.

The message is this:

> Registering converter from class microsoft.sql.DateTimeOffset to class java.time.OffsetDateTime as reading converter although it doesn't convert from a store-supported type! You might want to check your annotation setup at the converter implementation.

The relevant dependencies from the `pom.xml` are

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.3</version>
</parent>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>9.4.1.jre16</version>
</dependency>
```

I can of course suppress the logging of the warning by setting the log-level to `error` as suggested by answers to the [similar question asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60001034/how-to-remove-spring-data-customconversions-warnings-from-application-startup), e.g [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60001034/how-to-remove-spring-data-customconversions-warnings-from-application-startup/64678602#64678602) or [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60001034/how-to-remove-spring-data-customconversions-warnings-from-application-startup/65778289#65778289)

The entity POJO's date/datetime fields are `java.sql.Timestamp` or `java.util.Date` and the SQL Server tables have columns of type `date`, `datetime2` and `datetime`.
Mapping from POJO's to SQL is done by `org.springframework.data.repository.*/org.springframework.data.jdbc.repository.*` classes.

I would like to know how to correctly configure `CustomConversions` so as to avoid the warning altogether, if possible.